# Group by function / computed field with out "store = True"

Tags: odoo-11

I want to group by computed field (`type_client`).

I know that I should make it `store = True`, but I cannot because the values ​​are dynamic. Is there another option?

This is my function:

```
    def act_show_supect(self):
    for objctf in self:
        for client in self.env['res.partner'].search([('user_id.id', '=', self.user_id.id),
                                                      ('company_type', '=', 'company'),
                                                      ('type_client', '=', 'suspect')]):
            if client.type_client == 'suspect':
                objctf.ensure_one()
                res = objctf.env['ir.actions.act_window'].for_xml_id(
                    'base', 'action_partner_form')
                res.update(
                    context=dict(
                        objctf.env.context,
                        search_default_user_id_id=objctf.user_id.id,
                        search_default_type_client='suspect',
                    ),
                    domain=[('user_id.id', '=', objctf.user_id.id),
                            ('company_type', '=', 'company'),
                            ('type_client', '=', 'suspect')]
                )

                return res
```

And this is the error after execution:

```
  File "E:\odoo11.0\odoo\models.py", line 1908, in read_group
    result = self._read_group_raw(domain, fields, groupby, offset=offset, 
    limit=limit, orderby=orderby, lazy=lazy)

  File "E:\odoo11.0\odoo\models.py", line 1946, in _read_group_raw
    assert gb_field.store and gb_field.column_type, "Fields in 'groupby' 
    must be regular database-persisted fields (no function or related 
    fields), or function fields with store=True"

  AssertionError: Fields in 'groupby' must be regular database-persisted 
    fields (no function or related fields), or function fields with 
    store=True
```

And I want to group by:

`('type_client', '=', 'suspect')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, let's make a small workaround:

You have to add `@api.depends` (the fields that you depend on with your work) and this method will run every time you change the value of the depends fields.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23420331)

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @MattSummersgill answer was verified from the user who asked.

Comment: Even if the computed method was already decorated with `@api.depends` and it should be, the field should be stored. She says  that ``because the values ​​are dynamic``, but also the computed field values are computed and returned when requested, and it is not a reason to avoid storing the field values. Your answer is not a workaround, she probably declared the computed method without the ``depend`` decorator.